# ExcelDna get Excel UI element

Tags: c#, excel, xll

How can we retrieve the UI elements from the DNA file because I cannot seem to access to UI elements that are created inside the DNA file? I'm using Excel-Dna

Also :

What I would like to do is for a given cell I would like to get the values of the next N cells, but whenever I get the values of the cells I get an error saying 0x800A03EC. How can I get the values of a different than the current cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's how things are looking with Excel-DNA, I assumed I cannot interact with the UI. The only way I can have any connection with it is using the event system.

I solved the error 0x800A03EC by just carefully debugging the COM objects and finding the right properites to extract the value from.